# copy a file from local system to a docker hdfs container

Tags: docker, hdfs

I am trying to upload a file from my local system to Hadoop so that I can access it in the browse directory.

I tried of using Docker cp command source(my local windows file in documents) and destination(i tried to give my folder name which can be seen in localhost 50070 browse directory)-I don't see also any error in the terminal while using this command.

1)can you please guide me to upload a file to Hadoop directory.

Comment: How would you do it without Docker?  Does doing the exact same thing work?

Answer (score 0):

Add "cp" when make docker image. In Dockerfile.

https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile